# Make a pandas dataframe out of Series with numpy ndarrays (or 2d numpy array?)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas Series which contains 2d (?) numpy ndarrays of the same length with the shape (1 ,208), what would be the easiest way to make it into pandas dataframe with 208 columns?

[how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1PVR.png)

When i tried to make a numpy array, it turned out to be 3D, though I expected it to be 2D

```
x = []
for i in train_rdkit_desc:
    np.reshape(i, 208)
    x.append(i)

x = np.array(x)
x.shape
    
    (908, 1, 208)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32594136/how-to-construct-pandas-dataframe-from-series-of-arrays.  pd.DataFrame(series_to_convert.map(lambda x: x[0]).tolist())

Comment: `np.reshape(i, 208)` does not work in-place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way:

you can create a list with the name of your numpy arrays.
After that use method concatanation by columns (axis = 1):

df3 = pd.concat([numpy1,numpy2,..., numpyn], axis = 1)

Example:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
b = np.array([2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
df= pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(a), pd.DataFrame(b)])
```

Comment: this way doesn't work, i get a 1-column dataframe with ndarrays

Comment: Do you need 2D array with same vectors?

Comment: I changed my answer...